# Formula in worksheet and VBA works differently

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Cell A1 contains the number 25, which is right-aligned, implying it's a number, not text.

D1 contains the formula:

> ="" & A1

The 25 in D1 is left-aligned, implying it's text. That is confirmed by the following formula, which returns 1:

> =IF(D1="25",1,0)

The following VBA code puts 25 in F1 but the 25 is right-aligned and the IF test returns 0:

```
Range("F1") = "" & Range("A1")
```

Any explanation for the discrepancy?

E1 contains the following formula which gives a left-aligned 25 and the IF test returns 1:

> TEXT(A1,"0")

However, the following code gives a right-aligned 25 and the IF test returns 0:

```
Range("F1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("A1"), "0")
```

Not that I have to use the `TEXT` function. I just wonder why it works differently than when in a worksheet.

Any rule that tells when or what worksheet functions won't work in VBA code, or more precisely, will give different results than when in worksheet?

Comment: Use `Range("F1").Formula`

Comment: @0m3r, thanks for the reply but it gave the same result as without .Formula.

Answer (score 4):

When a data is written by vba into a cell, an internal type conversion function is called if required, that is if the data type is different from the cell's numberformat property.

You dont want that conversion function to be called.

To avoid this conversion function to be called, choose the proper Numberformat property for the cell before writing the data.

```
Range("b4").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("b4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("A1"), "0")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this code: Range("B1").ClearContents;Range("B1").NumberFormat = "@";Range("B1").FormulaLocal = Range("A1").Value. Although Format/Format Cells indicates the format of B1 is Text, "=TEXT(B1)" gave FALSE and "=ISNUMBER(B1)" gave TRUE. So far, I have been unable to put 25 into a cell as text via VBA code without invoking formula like STR or CSTR. I guess that's what they are for. My conclusion is: forget about putting number as text directly using VBA code without invoking a formula. Always use a formula such as STR or CSTR.

Comment: False.
The result of Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("A1"), "0") is already a String .So adding CStr is useless in that case.

Comment: I will delete my first suggestion ( using Formulalocal ). My second suggestion is the good one.

Comment: To put number as text directly using VBA code, you must first change the Numberformat property to String - Range("b1").NumberFormat = "@" - to avoid the VBA internal conversion function to be called.

Comment: Thanks. The trick is to set .NumberFormat="@" first then put a text/string 25 into the cell. If a numeric 25, such as =Range("A1"), is entered, the result is numeric.

Answer (score 2):

You simply get the wrong idea of what is a number in Excel.

in general ALL input is a string. Also writing "25" in a cell.
However: If possible, Excel will convert all inputs to a numerical value if possible. Also for dates and times.

To prevent this, you simply insert a `'` in front of your "text" in the cell.

The confusing part for you is the different behavior for formulas.
A formula will always output a "result" AND the "data type".

So `=1+1` will be numeric as the last action was math.
`=Left(1+1,1)` will be text as the last action was text-based.

For `=A1` it will simply copy the type. If there is a formula, then this will be the same. But if there is a "direct input" it will always try to convert to numerical and only be text if it can't be converted or if it starts with a leading `'` (`A1` itself does this already).

As a result: If there is a plain `25` in the cell, it will always be "numerical" no matter "how" you input the 25.

For newer Excel there is only one exception: if the cell formatting is text prior to entering a number, it will be treated as text (no converting). This does not apply if you change the formatting later.

---

Simple test:

- enter `25` in A1 (formatting general)
- enter `=ISNUMBER(A1)` in A2 (will be TRUE)
- set formatting for A1 to "text" (A2 will still be TRUE)
- enter `25` in A1 (now A2 will become FALSE)

This may fail (Excel confuses itself sometimes here). Try it with a new sheet. ;)

---

Hopefully you understood the fault in your logic ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm more interested in knowing why a worksheet formula converts a number to text but its VBA equivalent doesn't. Well, can't really say it's equivalent since it gives a different result.

Comment: @yky vba inserts 25. not the format. and just 25 is a number. no matter HOW you input the 25, it is a number. a worksheet formula outputs a value/string AND a data type.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, Application.WorksheetFunction.Text and the worksheet TEXT function work differently. I always thought Application.WorksheetFunction and worksheet function are the same thing.

Comment: @yky they are the same... the function outputs a "text"... but putting that "text" in a cell, excel will see it as a number.

Comment: @yky A better example: `?Application.WorksheetFunction.isnumber("25")` will be false. `?Application.WorksheetFunction.isnumber(25)` will be true. but either `Range("A1").Value = "25"` or `Range("A1").Value = 25` will lead to `?Application.WorksheetFunction.isnumber(Range("A1"))` to be true because there is only `25` in cell `A1` which is numeric.

Comment: @Reichel said:"they are the same... the function outputs a "text"... but putting that "text" in a cell, excel will see it as a number." But "=TEXT(A1,"0") gave TEXT, not number while the equivalent VBA code ,Application.WorksheetFunction.Text, gave number, not TEXT. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: @yky I'm not at a computer right now, but `?Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("A1"), "0"))` returns true?

Comment: It returned FALSE. So, indeed Excel silently converts TEXT 25 to number 25. Just wonder why Excel doesn't do the same to =TEXT(A1,"0"). Obviously, that would defeat the purpose of TEXT function but still Excel seems to know when to and when not to convert number to text.

Comment: @yky as said: "just the input in the cell as *direct input* does the convertion". `=TEXT(A1,"0")` outputs a value/string/whatever AND the data type. the type is string (text). however: this additional information (being text) gets lost as soon as the "value" is alone in the cell (no formula)

Answer (score 0):

The cell alignment says nothing about the cell's contents. Forget about anything being "implied" by it. When you start on a virgin worksheet the format for all cells is "General" which means that Excel will decide the format of what you enter. If you enter a number the format will be "Number". If you enter what looks like a date to Excel the format will be "Date", and for most other things the format will be "Text".
So, if you enter "    25" in a cell formatted as "General" Excel will recognise this to be a number despite the leading spaces, read it is numeric, and format the cell to the right. This will happen regardless of whether you made the entry by hand or used VBA. You can then proceed to format the alignment as you wish.
However, if you enter the number 25 in a cell formatted as Text Excel will recognise the number as text and display it formatted to the left (unless you expressly formatted the horizontal alignment to the right).

The best way to deal with any problems you might encounter in this regard, set the `NumberFormat` and `HorizontalAlignment` properties for the cells that you want to write to. You can do that both manually or using VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right that alignment doesn't tell anything. However, once a number is entered into a cell with "General" format, neither manually changing the cell format to TEXT nor .NumberFormat="@" will change it to TEXT. It stays as number as it fails the IF test.

Comment: The fault is in your test. Try `=IsNumber(D1)`. By comparison, `IsNumeric(Range("D1")` tests if a string consists of numbers. It will return True for both 25 and "25". Your question is too broad. You may expect better answers if you would state your problem. What do you want to do? And do you want to do it in the worksheet or using VBA?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to understand how Excel works. So, I'll have no surprise later. At the moment, there is no particular thing I want to do or accomplish. Still, applying .NumberFormat="@" to a number fails the ISTEXT test but ISNUMBER gives a positive result, meaning it is still a number, not being converted to TEXT.

Comment: This is a summary of my test results. Clearly, formulas work on worksheet but their corresponding VBA code don't. ="" & A1, ISNUMBER FALSE, ISTEXT TRUE;
=TEXT(A1,"0"), ISNUMBER FALSE, ISTEXT TRUE;

Range("G1").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("A1"), "0"),

ISNUMBER TRUE, ISTEXT FALSE; 

Range("G2") = "" & Range("A1"), ISNUMBER TRUE, ISTEXT FALSE

Comment: Worksheet functions are Excel's own. VBA is code working with Excel worksheets. If related functions aren't identical it isn't because they aren't working but because they work differently, usually for a reason. Excel is leaning over backward to make it easy for you to work with numbers without bothering whether they are technically text or numbers. If you can invent a situation where you need text, or one where you need numbers, both Excel and VBA have solutions for you, regardless of whether you want to read, display or write. Your tests lack purpose and, therefore, seem to create puzzles.

Comment: @Variatus yky simply misses the part of putting a text which can be a number into a cell. the output in fact IS text but putting it in to a cell makes excel silently convert it to a number.

Comment: @Reichel You are right that Excel silently converts text 25 to number 25.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet function when used in the worksheet behaves / works the same way as when used in VBA. Consider below code:

<sup>**Note:** Range("B1") contains a numeric value **25**</sup>

```
Dim r As Range, v As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction: Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

With Sheet1
    Set r = .Range("B1")
    v = r.Value2
    v = wf.Text(r.Value2, "0")
End With
```

Now using the local window, let us check the data type of variant `v`.

***SC1:*** *All variables un-initialized*
[image: All variables not initialized]

You can see, at the start that all variables have no value and the variant type `v` is empty.

***SC2:*** *Variables initialized and `v` assigned a value*

[image: Variant v set to Variant/Double]

After executing lines up to `v = r.value2`, all variable types were confirmed (e.g. `Range/Range` etc.) and variant `v` is now `Variant/Double`.

***SC3:*** *Re-assign a value on `v` but using worksheet function `Text`*

[image]

Executing the last line which uses the worksheet function `Text`, variant `v` type becomes `Variant/String`. I think this confirms that the function `Text` works as expected converting the numeric `25` into a string type.

As for the behavior of passing `VBA` generated value to worksheet, it is covered by [Docmarti's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987977/2685412) above.